# Ubuntu live USB boot freezes with "ACPI PCC probe failed"

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb, acpi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a Toshiba laptop (not sure exact model, but it's about 4 years old, and was pretty cheap at the time). It came with windows 8, now has windows 10, and it's super slow, so I'm trying to salvage it by putting linux on it. I've installed Ubuntu many times on other computers, but I've never encountered this problem before. I get as far as the boot menu (I'm given options of "Try Ubuntu without installing", "Install Ubuntu", "OEM Install", etc. Whichever option I pick, the screen is blank for a couple seconds, then it gives me this:

```
[    0.041462] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
[   10.423311] ACPI PCC probe failed.
```

Then it just freezes, and doesn't do anything. The only way to get out is by forcing shutdown. What's going on?

I'm using a live image (14.04.3) installed with unetbootin.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem with my Acer Aspire E 15 E5-511-p214.

The problem relates to something that has changed in relation to the kernel and the problem seems to start for me from kernel 3.18 and later. I am running 3.14 now and its fine. The issue somehow relates to UEFI and whether secure boot is enabled. Essentially I have found that 3.18 kernels and later won't boot unless secure boot is enabled but as far as I know only Ubuntu boots with secure boot.

So the answer to this question is for Ubuntu linux users:

- enable secure boot in the UEFI menu or put it in legacy mode.

For other linux users going back to some pre 3.18 kernel, 3.14 works well for me or put it in legacy mode.

The problem with putting it in legacy mode is dual booting with an existing Windows install won't be possible.